# What is wrong with this please?

Tags: php

The value of $width is getting echoed fine and tallies with the browser width but the if statement just doesnt execute.

```
<?php 
$width = "<script>document.write(window.outerWidth); </script>";
echo($width);
if ($width > 599) {
    echo do_shortcode('[codepeople-html5-media-player id="1"]');
} else {?>
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/copy-jandp-logo2.png" alt="logo" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: $width is a string, not a number.... defining a string containing `$width = "<script>document.write(window.outerWidth); </script>"` on a webserver running PHP doesn't automagically execute a javascript function on a web browser and return the result to PHP on the server

Comment: Probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: all this seems like front-end code, why even use PHP there? it could all be done with JS.

Comment: you are mixind server side parsing with client-side parsing. maybe do and ajax call which includes your width, parse your shortcode and finally return it and display it. or better use CSS (media query) to hide your unwanted section and display your image

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment use CSS media query to do your desired effect.

PHP Code:

```
echo '<div class="codepeople-sc">', do_shortcode('[codepeople-html5-media-player id="1"]'), '</div>';
echo '<div class="codepeople-img"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/copy-jandp-logo2.png" alt="logo" /></div>';
```

CSS Style:

```
.codepeople-sc{ display: none; }
.codepeople-img{ display: block; }
@media (min-width: 599px){
    .codepeople-sc{ display: block; }
    .codepeople-img{ display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In your PHP code, `$width` is a string. So to achieve what you want by changing `if ($width > 599)` to `if ( strlen( $width ) > 599 )`

Comment: why would OP want string length? Obviously they are trying to compare the result of `window.outerWidth`, I think the *real* problem is coming from trying to mix JS and PHP

Comment: if anything you probably want `parseInt` not `strlen`... regardless, the use of PHP in that code is horrible; good example of Spaghetti Code

Comment: Oops! I didn't "read" the intention of the OP. Apparently, OP wants to know if `$width` is more than `599`, not if length of `$width` is more than `599`. However, @musefan is right: mixing JS with PHP is very bad. In this context, it is rather worse:)

Answer (score -3):

When you assign anything under double quotes to a variable it is a string.
***ie: str = "I am a string"; # String***

***ie: num = 23; # number***

When you execute your if statement the $width is a string comparing
to a number, therefore, it will not execute. If you create a string 
*(ie: x="15")* you can cast that to an integer.

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: and do you think that string will parse to an int?

Comment: @musefan Lol no that string will not parse to an int.

Comment: it will always be a string containing "<script>...." PHP will not execute the JS code.

Comment: don't mix server side parsing with client side parsing